# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (MySQLdb.ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'testdb.car' doesn't exist")

Tags: python, fastapi

Here is my code and I don't know why I face this issue. this issue always show me that automatic table is not create in database why it's show me always.
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (MySQLdb.ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'testdb.car' doesn't exist")
[SQL: SELECT car.id AS car_id, car.manufacturer AS car_manufacturer, car.`modelName` AS `car_modelName`, car.cc AS car_cc, car.`onRoadPrice` AS `car_onRoadPrice`, car.`seatingCapacity` AS `car_seatingCapacity`, car.`gearBox` AS `car_gearBox`, car.`fuelType` AS `car_fuelType`
FROM car
WHERE car.manufacturer = %s AND car.`modelName` = %s
LIMIT %s]

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

import config

DATABASE_URL = config.DATABASE_URL

db_engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=db_engine)

Base = declarative_base()

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=db_engine)

def get_db():
    """
    Function to generate db session
    :return: Session
    """
    db = None
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

import enum

from sqlalchemy.schema import Column
from sqlalchemy.types import Enum, Integer, String

from database import Base, db_engine


class FuelType(str, enum.Enum):
    Petrol = "Petrol"
    Diesel = "Diesel"


class CarInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "car"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    manufacturer = Column(String)
    modelName = Column(String)
    cc = Column(Integer)
    onRoadPrice = Column(Integer)
    seatingCapacity = Column(Integer)
    gearBox = Column(Integer)
    fuelType = Column(Enum(FuelType))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Base.metadata.create_all(bind=db_engine)` creates tables for all the models registered with `Base.metadata`.  Therefore it must be called *after* all the model definitions have been executed, otherwise the tables for model definitions that have not been executed will not be created.

Move  `Base.metadata.create_all(bind=db_engine)`to after your model class definitions.

Comment: already tried but same result. 
class FuelType(str, enum.Enum):
    Petrol = "Petrol"
    Diesel = "Diesel"


class CarInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "car"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    manufacturer = Column(String)
    modelName = Column(String)
    cc = Column(Integer)
    onRoadPrice = Column(Integer)
    seatingCapacity = Column(Integer)
    gearBox = Column(Integer)
    fuelType = Column(Enum(FuelType))
    
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=db_engine)